# multiply one column by a column in another table

Tags: mysql

I've created  table1 that i can update by a form, so if I need to change a price percentage I can without needing to edit code.
I import and create a temp table2 from a csv file. The new temp table2 has the cost of items so I need to multiply by a percentage to get the selling price, hence the price percentage in table1.

percent is a column in a table1 and I want to select it by row id, importID is the column ID, both of these are in table1 that I can update by a form. I need to select by row id for future growth and multiple percentages.

I want to multiply the price column in the temp table2 by the percent column in my permanent table1.

Here is the part that is giving me a syntax error

```
  SELECT percent FROM my_table1 WHERE importID = 1
```

here is the pricing update code

```
  UPDATE my_temp_table2
  SELECT percent FROM my_table1 WHERE importID = 1
  SET Price = (Price * percent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be

```
UPDATE my_temp_table2
SET Price = Price * (SELECT percent FROM my_table1 WHERE importID = 1);
```

This multiplies all prices in my_temp_table2 with the one price found in my_table1 for importID 1.

Here is an alternative using a variable:

```
SELECT @percent := percent
FROM my_table1 WHERE importID = 1;

UPDATE my_temp_table2
SET Price = Price * @percent;
```

Comment: I appreciate the help from everyone

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to "plug it into a variable", which isn't exactly how SQL operates.

How about something like this:

```
UPDATE my_temp_table2
SET Price = Price * (SELECT percent FROM my_table1 WHERE importID = 1);
```

It isn't super performant, but for a one-time update it should work fine.

Comment: @MarcusAdams - while i appreciate your enthusiasm, the edit you made was entirely stylistic in nature, zero impact on performance or result. i don't really care for something like this, but u will make many coders unhappy if you choose to "fix" their code with stylistic changes such as this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update the `Price` column in ALL rows of `my_temp_table2`?  By the value of the `percent` column from a single row returned from `my_table1`?

Here's one way to achieve that:

```
UPDATE my_temp_table2 t
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT p.percent
           FROM my_table1 p
          WHERE p.importID = 1
          ORDER BY p.percent
          LIMIT 1
       ) q
   SET t.Price = t.Price * q.percent
```

If your question indicated `importID` is the `PRIMARY KEY` (or a `UNIQUE KEY`) in `my_table1`, you could avoid the inline view. The purpose of the LIMIT and ORDER BY clauses in the inline view query is to ensure that no more than 1 row is returned, and to make the result deterministic. (There are other ways to accomplish this, e.g. a `MIN()` or `MAX()` aggregate.)

If `importID` is UNIQUE in `my_table1`, you could simplify the query above, and just reference the table without using an inline view:

```
UPDATE my_temp_table2 t
  JOIN my_table1 q
    ON q.importID = 1
   SET t.Price = t.Price * q.percent
```

It's often beneficial to write this as a SELECT statement first, before you run the UPDATE. Just replace the `UPDATE` keyword with `SELECT ... FROM`, and remove the `SET` clause. For example:

```
SELECT t.Price             AS `old_price`
     , q.percent           AS `percent`
     , t.Price * q.percent AS `new_price`
  FROM my_temp_table2 t
  JOIN my_table1 q
    ON q.importID = 1
```

Change that back into an UPDATE by replacing `SELECT ... FROM` with the `UPDATE` keyword, and add a `SET` clause (to assign the result of the expression that returns new_price, to the Price column.

Note that if no matching row is found in `my_table1`, the query/update will return/update zero rows.

If you don't use a JOIN operation, and you instead use a subquery in the `SET` clause, a `NULL` value returned by the subquery will result in a `NULL` value assigned to the `Price` column.